# ¿Cómo actualizo los campos seleccionados con un checkbox?

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo le dé al botón `Autorizar seleccionados` cambie el `statusAut` a `Autorizada`, pero solo del registro que haya seleccionado con el `checkbox`. La verdad no sé si pueda, quiero que en el registro me marque autorizada.

[image: TABLA DE COMPRAS]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>ICOM INGENIERÍA</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/intranet/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/intranet/assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/intranet/assets/examples.css">
    <script src="//localhost/intranet/assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost/intranet/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost/intranet/assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost/intranet/ga.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
<b><script type="text/javascript" > var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"); var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado"); var f=new Date(); document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + " " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear()); </script><b><br>
<script type="text/javascript" > function startTime(){ today=new Date(); h=today.getHours(); m=today.getMinutes(); s=today.getSeconds(); m=checkTime(m); s=checkTime(s); document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s; t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);} function checkTime(i) {if (i<10) {i="0" + i;}return i;} window.onload=function(){startTime();} </script> 
<b><div id="reloj" ></div><b>
</a>
</div>
 <form method="post" action="add_reg2.php"> 
    <div class="container">
        <h4>LISTADO DE ORDENES DE COMPRA</h4>
        <button type="submit" name= "enviar" value= "Aceptar informacion"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Autorizar Seleccionados</button><br>
        <table id="table"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-height="430"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-search="true">         
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="idCompra" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                <th data-field="CveSuc">CLIENTE</th>
                <th data-field="CeCo" >CeCo</th>
                <th data-field="OrdenComp">#ORDEN</th>
                <th data-field="NomProv">PROVEEDOR</th>
                <th data-field="SubtPed" >SUBTOTAL</th>
                <th data-field="TotalPed" >TOTAL</th>
                <th data-field="StatusPart" >STATUS PART.</th>
                <th data-field="FalltaPed">FECHA PEDIDO</th>
                <th data-field="NomUser" >USUARIO</th>
                <th data-field="statusAut">STATUS AUT.</th>
                <th data-field="FechHoraAut">FECHA Y HORA AUT.</th>
            </tr>     
            </thead>
            <?php  
      $db_host="localhost";
      $db_user="root";
      $db_password= "";
      $db_name="localicom";
      $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
      $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM vistacompras";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
      {
        echo utf8_encode("<tr><td width=\"8%\">" . $row["idCompra"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"15%\">" .$row["CveSuc"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">" . $row["Ceco"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"15%\">" . $row["OrdenComp"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"15%\">" . $row["NomProv"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">$" .$row["SubtPed"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">$" .$row["TotalPed"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"6%\">" . $row["StatusPart"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"15%\">" . $row["FalltaPed"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">" . $row["NomUser"] . "</td>");
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"6%\">" .$row["statusAut"] . "</td>");  
        echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">" . $row["FechHoraAut"]. "</td></tr>");

     }
       mysqli_free_result($resultado);
       mysqli_close($db_connection);
       ?>
        </table>
         <button type="button" ng-click="eliminaUsuario()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancelar</button>
         <button type="submit" name= "enviar" value= "Aceptar informacion"class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

el archivo al que hago referencia es add_reg2.php

solo es un update a la tabla

por favor si alguien me pudiera decir de que forma jalar los datos seleccionados con el checkbox se los agradecería.

Comment: no solo añadas código, tambie nuna descripcion de lo que queres hacer

Comment: Hola sonjer, tal y como te dice Rene, es importante que añadas una descripción a tu pregunta.

Comment: ok xD, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando seleccione una campo con el checbox y le de al botón autorizar registro me actualice el status a autorizado pero solo de ese registro q seleccione, la verdad desconozco si se pueda hacer con varios registros a mismo tiempo, la verdad soy novato en programación y espero me puedan encaminar un poco con lo que debería hacer, Gracias !!!

Comment: Cuéntanos también en tu pregunta qué has intentado/qué te falla :). Y todo el código que no sea relevante no hace falta que lo compartas =P

Comment: mira el código para el botón para la actualización del registro que seleccione con el checkbox no lo he hecho porque no se como hacerlo, como dije soy novato y necesito una idea de como hacerlo el único código que tengo es el que subí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema, hacer lo siguiente:

Hay que agregar una columna nueva a tu tabla, ya que como utilizaste la propiedad de checkbox por defaul de table bootstrap nada mas funciona como tal. en este caso quedaria esta parte como

```
<th data-field="id" data-checkbox="true"></th>
<th data-field="idCompra"></th>
```

y el PHP donde haces el while

```
echo "<tr><td width=\"8%\"></td>";
echo utf8_encode("<td width=\"8%\">" . $row["id_checkbox"] . "</td>");
```

El Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var checkedRows = new Array();
            //Cuando se da clic al checkbox este selecciona las propiedades de la tabla..
            $('#table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
                  checkedRows.push({id: row.idCompra});
                  console.log(checkedRows);
                });

                $('#table').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
                  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
                    if (value.id === row.id) {
                      checkedRows.splice(index,1);
                    }
                  });
                  console.log(checkedRows);
                });
//Aqui es donde actualizas tu tabla asignale un id al botón
$('button#acpt').on("click",function(e){
         var array = {data: checkedRows};
         var paramJSON = JSON.stringify(array);

         console.log(array);
          $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'add_reg2.php',
                data: { data: paramJSON },
                cache:false })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                  console.log(msg);
                location.reload()
              });

              e.preventDefault();              
        });
});
```

Y el php que recibe los datos

```
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    //var_dump($data);
    foreach($data->data as $mydata)
    {
        $MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE vistacompras SET statusAut='Autorizada' WHERE idCompra=".$mydata->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, probare el código y les diré si me funciona estaba en espera de una respuesta.

Comment: Cig use tu codigo pero al dar click al boton solo me direcciona al archivo add_reg2.php y no me causa ningun error, ni se ejecuta la consulta, no se si se deba  a que estoy usando boostrap y el data-checkbox no funcione asi.

Comment: Quita el action del form yo replique tu codigo en local y funciona perfecto, esto porque lo que yo hice, lo hace mediante ajax

Comment: amigo Cig disculpa mi ignorancia pero donde debo de meter el código php porque al dar clic al botón solo me refresca la pagina sin mandar ningun error pero tampoco actualiza los datos. El código php lo puse abajo del script.

Comment: @sonjer debería ser un archivo php aparte en el mismo lugar donde tienes el el archivo actual, o donde quieras... nada mas en el script de javascript, hay que cambiar la ruta si deseas ponerlo en otro lado

Comment: ok amigo gracias por responder yo te aviso que sucede jejeje, gracias por estar pendiente.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo si me funciono

Comment: El problema era la ruta a la que yo hacia referencia xD

Comment: Excelente!! a seguir...

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo completo como podría quedar, he creado uno sin `bootstrap` de manera simple, es simplemente para orientarte.

Código HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="add_reg2.php"> 
  <table>        
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>CLIENTE</th>
      <th>CeCo</th>
      <th>ORDEN</th>  
      //Etc.     
    </tr> 

    <?php

    //Conexión Mysql.
    require_once'tuconexion.php';

    //Sentencia SQL.
    $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM vistacompras";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db_connection,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['idCompra']; ?>" /></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['CveSuc']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['Ceco']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['OrdenComp']; ?></td>      
    </tr> 
    <?php
    }//Fin while

    mysqli_close($db_connection); 
    ?>   

  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="autorizados" value="Autorizar seleccionados" />
</form>
```

Código PHP: (add_reg2.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['autorizados'])) { 

    //Conexión Mysql.
    require_once'tuconexion.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    //var_dump($id);
    $count = count($id);
    //Mensaje con el cambio.        
    $status = 'AUTORIZADA';

    //Rebuscamos en busca de resultados $_POST (id selecionados).
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        //Actualizamos Base de datos.
        mysqli_query($db_connection,"UPDATE vistacompras SET statusAUT='$status'
        WHERE idCompra='$id[$i]' LIMIT 1");

    }

    mysqli_close($db_connection);    
    echo "Se actualizo correctamente";     
}
```